# Google Shortener API limitation

Tags: php, google-api, google-url-shortener

We are using Google Shortener in our projects, it seems Google has two limitations :

- 100 requests per user in 100 second
- 1000000 requests per day.
  [image: google limitation]

At the 11:00 AM we have a cron job which runs a code and needs to short about 15,000 URLs,

Yesterday we  used just one key, but today we add 6 keys to bypass this limitation and each minute use one of them with the following code

```
    $googleAPIKeys = [
        'KEY1CODE',
        'KEY2CODE',
        'KEY3CODE',
        'KEY4CODE',
        'KEY5CODE',
        'KEY6CODE'
    ];
    $roundRobinKey = date('i') % count($googleAPIKeys);
    try {
        $req = $client->post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=' . $googleAPIKeys[$roundRobinKey], [
            'json' => [
                'longUrl' => $url
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        return $url;
    }

    $result = json_decode($req->getBody()->getContents());
```

But still faced with 403 (**limitations exceed**)
[image]

[image]

**it seems strange, Why This happening? What is the true limitation of shortener google service?**
**how can I bypass this limitation?**

**Another note:** in the single key scenario if you limitation exceed ( 100 per 100 seconds) if you try to use that key again after 5 min still faced with 403 limitations exceed problem !!!
it seems google limitations is not as they said !!!

**Update**

After reading [Standard Query Parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/parameters) and [Capping API usage](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7035610)
I'd changed my request to the following

```
  $req = $client->post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?quotaUser=' . $userID . '&key=' . $myKey, [
    'json' => [
        'longUrl' => $url
    ]
]);
```

Which `userID` is unique userID per request ( because we generate each url per user) . but still facing with 403 !!!

[image]

Any Idea?

Comment: their api is probably smart enough to realise all the requests are coming from the same source

Comment: For the record I did not down vote the question but thanks for the vote of confidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is going to be project and user based.  however it can also be ip based.

work arounds

1. create multiple projects on Google developers console.  each with one API key.
2. send the optional parm userid with each request useing a random variable.
3. check the quota tab in developers console see if you can increase the quota it will have a pencil icon.

Note the amount of time you are locked out should be around an hour.

> quotaUser Alternative to userIp.   Lets you enforce per-user quotas
>   from a server-side application even in cases when the user's IP
>   address is unknown. This can occur, for example, with applications
>   that run cron jobs on App Engine on a user's behalf. You can choose
>   any arbitrary string that uniquely identifies a user, but it is
>   limited to 40 characters. Overrides userIp if both are provided. Learn
>   more about Capping API usage.

You add it as an additional parm in your request

```
quotaUser=xxxx
```

Comment: thank you for your attention, how can I send userid as a param to the endpoint?

Comment: check update i had the name wrong btw this wont always work they can see you are sendimg from the same ip

Comment: a random string you want to use to identity the user.  this will not give you unlimited us they can still see its coming from the same ip but it should help

Comment: I'll try it and inform you about the result. I don't want unlimited access, just want to 20,0000 requests per one specified hour in a day.

Comment: I've tried it but unfortunately hasn't worked for me and after 4000 request by 4000 unique userId  facing with 403 :(

Comment: I've updated my question, do you have any idea why it happening?

Comment: it's happening because you are sending the request from the same ip address this is flood protection.    you need to share the API with others.  slow down your calls there is no way to increase this quota.

Comment: @DaImTo is there a way to increase the limit to more than 100 requests per 100 seconds?

Comment: No that quote is not extendedable

Comment: @DaImTo you can see on documentation , using quotaUser make it as unquie IP .  >quotaUser An arbitrary string that uniquely identifies a user. 
Lets you enforce per-user quotas from a server-side application even in cases when the user's IP address is unknown. This can occur, for example, with applications that run cron jobs on App Engine on a user's behalf.
You can choose any arbitrary string that uniquely identifies a user, but it is limited to 40 characters.

Comment: Google Knows the ip its the address the request is coming from.   You could send a random value to quotaUser if you like.  It helps a bit but eventually Google figures out what you are doing and your still going to get quota based on the IP address of the machine running the request.

Comment: @DaImTo my users are unique, I mean per request I send a unique user id  as  quotaUser

Comment: Yup should work but only limited.  Don't expect to get 100 requests per second per user running via a cron job behind the same IP address.   Per user request quota works best when its different machine making the request.

Comment: @DaImTo , it should work, but didn't, nothing is mentioned in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/parameters about IP and unqiue IP, do you have any suggestion? we are struggling with this issue yet.

Comment: My suggestion is to give up and accept the limitation.   I created a custom SSIS task which accessed the Google Analytics api.   I tried everything for over a year to get it to run faster and not hit this quota.    Slow down and try again.   This was the best i ever came up with https://www.daimto.com/google-apis-flood-buster/

Comment: @DaImTo, unfortunately, we're using PHP and PHP sucks in multithreading and we can't block sleep a thread for 1 sec. as you know google is going to shutdown goo.gl service ( replace it with FDL) by next year and we are going to implement  to implement our shortener service on june, we just need temporary solution to  decrease our sms costs.. thank you for attention and time.

Comment: @DaImTo sure, I'm looking for a way to concern the google that accepts the request with quotaUser as unique user , I'll add it to your answer and if couldn't find I'll accept your answer in both conditions;-). thanks for time.